# Keycloak - Resource based Role & scope base auth

Tags: keycloak

i have a scenario where i want to restrict the user in keycloak

i have user

user can have access to multiple accounts
in multiple accounts, use can be Admin or agent (reader)

```
user
|
|
|-------account-1
|            |
|            |-------admin
|-------account-2
|            |
|            |-------agent
```

How can we map this in Keycloak with Policy, Permission, and role?

any reference document any example really helpful

also based from : [Resources, scopes, permissions and policies in keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186537/resources-scopes-permissions-and-policies-in-keycloak/58906945?noredirect=1#comment117866119_58906945)

From the answer of Andy, i have created one resource **Account** and role admin & agent.

created same policies as in example.

i am looking forward to add scopes (auth scope) and roles to JWT token how to map that part so that API gateway or service can verify further.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/

Comment: @dreamcrash i have checked it RBAC and all but i not sure about creating resource and policy how it will. in my case i think Account will be resource. Roles will be Admin and Agent. i am stuk with policy and permission.

Comment: Hmm - I think further clarification is needed. Are you trying to implement some sort of [user impersonation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#impersonation)?

Comment: @Andy no i read document, what i am basically looking forward my application has two types of userroles `admin` and `agent`. users may have access to multiple accounts. in some account user might be `admin` or `agent`

Comment: based on your this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58906945/12556258....i have created client roles, resource and eveything. now i want basic auth scope and roles into JWT so restrict user at API gateway level. Please suggest better way also if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Ah I see. I'll get back to you tomorrow (if you you haven't received an answer by then).

Comment: @Andy i don't think anyone will join the party.

Comment: Hey, you never know but no worries :) I'm at work right now but I promise I will get back to you. What is your timezone? Mines EST - we can always coordinate to chat as well.

Comment: i am in IST timezone, if you can please share the point of contact or LinkedIn profile we can discuss in chat also there.

Comment: We can use this [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230103/room-for-andy-and-chagan) I'll periodically check on it an reply. Might not be as quick since it's late here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> @changa, I've rewritten my answer based on our discussion. Hope this helps!

Let me first clarify some key areas before I answer. My main focus on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186537/resources-scopes-permissions-and-policies-in-keycloak/58906945#58906945) that you've linked was really on how to play around the `Evaluate` tool and I didn't really dive too deeply into some of the concepts - so let's do that :)

In Keycloak, you'll encounter Client and Authorization Scopes. For a formal definition of these terms please check out the [Core Concepts and Terms](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/) in the Server Administration Guide, but simply put:

**Client Scopes** are scopes which are *granted* to clients when they are requested via the `scope` parameter (once the resource owner permits it). Note that there's also the concept of `Default Client Scope` but I've chosen to keep things simple. Furthermore, you can leverage protocol and role scope mappers to tailor what claims and assertions are present in the access token.

**Authorization Scopes** on the other hand are *granted* to clients after successful evaluation of the policies against a protected resource. These scopes are not granted to clients based on user consent.

The key differences between the two is really when and how a client obtains these scopes. To help you visualize all of this, here's a scenario:

1. A renowned martial artist called `Bob` authenticates via Keycloak
2. `Bob` get presented with a consent screen where he is asked to share his name, his fighting style and his age.
3. `Bob` chooses to give access to his name and fighting style but he declines to share his age.
4. When we inspect the token now, we would see the following (completely made up) entries for the `scope` attribute of the access token: `name` and `fighting_style`.
5. Additionally, let's assume that we've set up a couple of protocol mappers (e.g. User Attribute Mapper Type - there are a ton) to display the values for full name and fighting style via the following token claims: `fighter_name` and `martial_arts` when the two `Client Scopes` above are present in the access token. In addition to two previously mentioned scopes, we would also see something like `fighter_name: Robert Richards` and `martial_arts: Freestyle Karate` when examining the access token.

   - **Side Note**: Given the length of this answer, I've decided to skip this topic but please check out this [awesome video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duawSV69LDI) at around the 7 minute mark along with the associated [GitHub Project](https://github.com/stianst/keycloak-containers-demo) for more information. The README is pretty good.
6. Additionally, let's assume that `Bob` is mapped to a realm role called `Contestant` and a client role of `Fighter` and we did place any restrictions in Keycloak when it comes to sharing this info. So in addition to all the things mentioned above, we would see that information inside the token as well.

   - Needless to say, this is an oversimplification on my part as I'm simply setting up the stage for demo. purposes and there's much more information inside the access token.
7. `Bob` doesn't like how the tournament bracket is laid out as he's eager to fight the world champ as soon as possible, so he attempts to change his placement by sending a request against `tournament/tekken6/bracket/{id}`. This resource is associated with the scope `bracket:modify`. Additionally, there is a permission which associates the resource in question with a role based policy named `Referee Role Required`. If `Bob` were a `Referee` then he would be granted the `bracket:modify` scope but since he isn't, then he is denied that scope.

   - I've barely touched the surface when it comes to the inner workings of the Authorization process in Keycloak. For more information, check out this [practical guide](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/authorization_services/topics/service-authorization-uma-authz-process.adoc). You can do some pretty cool stuff with UMA.

Ok, so that's enough theory. Let's set up our environment to demo all of this. I'm using the following:

- A realm called `demo`
- A client called `my-demo-client`
- A client scope called `client_roles`
- 2 users - `paul` and `law`
- Two realms level roles - `Admin` and `Reader`
- Two client level roles - `demo-admin` and `demo-reader`

> Please note that I will using Keycloak 12.0.4 and I will skip almost **all** the basic setup instructions. I will only share the relevant bits. If you're not sure how to set this all up, please check out the [Getting Started Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186537/resources-scopes-permissions-and-policies-in-keycloak). The answer contains steps for version 8 but the differences are very minor as far as I could tell.

#### Associating Users And Roles

In order to associate `paul` with the `Admin`, `Reader`, `bank-admin` and `bank-reader` roles, please do the following:

- Click on `Users` > `View all users` > Click on the `ID` value for `paul` > Click on `Role Mappings` > Under `Realm Roles` move `Admin` and `Reader` under `Assigned Roles` > Select `my-demo-client` under the `Client Roles` select box and move `demo-admin` and `demo-reader` under `Assigned Roles` like so

[image]

- As for `law` we'll just associate him with `Reader` and `bank-reader`.

#### Associating a client scope with a client

Create a Client Scope by:

- Clicking on the `Client Scopes` link on the left > Click on `Create` > Enter `custom-client-scope` for the `Name` field and Hit Save. It should look like this

[image]

- Click on `Clients` on the left > Select the `my-demo-client` > Click on the `Client Scopes` tab at the top > and let's just move it to `Assigned Default Client Scopes` for convenience.

#### Inspecting the Access Token

We can easily generate an access token for our setup via Keycloak to see what it looks like. In order to do so:

- Click on `Evaluate` tab under `Client Scopes`.
- Select `paul` as the user
- Click on the blue `Evaluate` button
- Click on `Generated Access Token`. While inspecting the token, look for:

  - `resource_access` to see client level roles associated with `paul`
  - `realm_access` to see `paul`'s realm level roles
  - `scope` to see the `Client Scope` that we created called `custom-client-scope`
    [image]
    [image]
- If you generate a token for `law`, you would see less roles when compared to `paul`.

#### Obtaining a Scope After Policy Evaluation

Continuing with our setup:

- I've created an `account/{id}` resource with two `Authorization Scopes` called `account:read` and `account:modify` like so

[image]

- Additionally, I've created two role based policies called `Only Reader Role Policy` and `Only Admin Role Policy` where the former requires the `Reader` realm role while the latter requires the `Admin` realm role. Here's an example for reference.

[image]

- Note that you can further enhance that policy at the client level if you wish but to keep things simple, I chose not to do so.
- Furthermore, I've created two scoped based permissions called `Read Account Scope Permission` and `Modify Account Scope Permission`.
- The `Read Account Scope Permission` will grant the `account:read` `Authorization Scope` if the user is either an `Admin` **or** a `Reader`. One key thing to notice here is the the Decision Strategy has to be set to `Affirmative` in order to achieve this behavior.

[image]

- `Modify Account Permission` on the other hand grants the `account:modify` `Authorization Scope` to users with the `Admin` role.

[image]

- Now, if you choose the evaluate the user `paul` (remember he is both `Admin` and `Reader`) against the `Account Resource`, he will be granted both the `account:read` and `account:modify` `Authorization Scopes`. Let's see if this true. Here's our `Evaluate` screen and notice that I did not associate any roles with `paul` since this was already done via the `Users` > `Role Mappings` tab

[image]

- And here are the results of that evaluation as predicted

[image]

- Here is the evaluation result for `law`. Since he's not an `Admin` he'll be denied the `account:modify` scope but he'll be granted the `account:read` scope.

[image]

- And finally, we can further confirm this by click on `Show Authorization Data` which shows the permissions inside the access token for `law`

[image]

Hopefully this helps you see where each piece of the puzzle fits in your architecture. Cheers!

Comment: @chagan  I hope this helps. I feel like I'm forgetting something....hmmm...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andy. for taking out time and writing the answer will all minor details. in your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186537/resources-scopes-permissions-and-policies-in-keycloak/58906945#58906945....you mentioned about RBAC and scope permission.

Comment: i have implemented some scope base policies along with resources and auth scope (as per answer example it is `account:view`)  now how can i add this auth scope to `account:view` to JWT token that is what i am stuck at.

Comment: Just for ref if in facing --data-urlencode error : `curl -X POST \
  https://keycloak.example.tk/auth/realms/<YourRealm>/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=app-client&grant_type=password&scope=openid&username=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>&client_secret=<CLIENT-SECRET>'`

Comment: @HarshManvar oh, I didn't realize - my mistake sorry. I took the curl straight from POSTMAN. I'll update the answer in a bit. Thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: @changan ah, scopes. I knew I forgot something. Give me a few hours, sorry about that,

Comment: No worries @Andy please take your time it's fine. also i have added some messages in chat room if you can please check that out also that would be really helpful.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230103/room-for-andy-and-chagan

Comment: this guy has explained question better way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62537162/set-scopes-for-access-token-returned-by-keycloak

Comment: @chagan I understand you issue no worries. We will definitely figure it out. I replied :)

Comment: Perfect no worries, please take your time.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Andy for all the help and everything for sharing the demo and clearing out all doubts. You saved my dayssssss...!

Comment: @chagan My pleasure! And thank you also for the feedback. I'm going to update my answer here soon and use this oppurtunity to clear/expand on some of the existing concepts! Check back in a couple of days :)