# Realm policies are being ignored while getting token

Tags: keycloak

I have two realms, a public webapp and an extranet where only employees can access.
I have tried setting group policies.

When I try to connect with an non-employee user, keycloak still returns the access token.

What did I miss?

EDIT.

I made a mistake, I only have 2 clients.

[image]

Comment: can you share urls you are using when trying to get access tokens for both the realms

Comment: @Abhijeet I made a mistake, I only have 2 clients.

Comment: If both clients are from same Realm then access token from one client can be used to access other client

Comment: So I should create another realm

Comment: It's one of the solution, but you can limit the access via other ways as well

Answer (score 1):

You have to limit the access granted to your access token to achieve this. There are three ways to do it (that I know of)

1. **Audience**: Allows listing the resource providers that should accept an access token.
2. **Roles**: Through controlling what roles a client has access to, it is
   possible to control what roles an application can access on behalf
   of the user.
3. **Scope**: In Keycloak, scopes are created through client scopes, and an
   application can only have access to a specific list of scopes.

You can look at this [example](https://usmanshahid.medium.com/levels-of-access-control-through-keycloak-part-3-access-control-through-roles-and-tokens-a1744c04895e) which explains the flow on how to achieve this using role based method. You can [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660297/keycloak-resource-based-role-scope-base-auth) this as well.